# Why is it possible to assume a contradiction in a disjunctive syllogism?

Tags: logic

I was reading about the [principle of explosion](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) with this example:

> Assume two contradictory premises: A.) 'All ice cream is frozen.'; B.)
>   'Not all ice cream is frozen.' Now, just to show that it's possible,
>   say one wants to use those two premises to prove that: C.) 'Words
>   don't exist'.
>
> To do so, construct a disjunction out of A and C: 'All ice cream is
>   frozen or words don't exist.'
>
> This statement appears to be perfectly acceptable here because it
>   holds true under any of these three circumstances:
>   1. All ice cream is frozen.
>   2. Words don't exist.
>   3. All ice cream is frozen and words don't exist. (Of which at least the first one is true because it was assumed as a premise.)
>
> Now use that disjunction for a disjunctive syllogism: 'All ice cream
>   is frozen or words don't exist. Not all ice cream is frozen. Therefore
>   words don't exist.'
>
> This also appears to be perfectly acceptable here because if it is
>   said that at least one of A or C are true, then when it turns out A is
>   not true (which is B, which has been accepted as a premise), at least
>   it can be held that C is true.

However, the only issue I have with this is we assumed B is true at the beginning. So if B is true, then how are we sure that C is true? Aren't we just returning back to the original disjunction, but now saying "not all ice cream is frozen or words don't exist"? Or am I misinterpreting when they say "assume two contradictory premises" - I'm not sure if they mean to assume they're both true or not. I can see how a disjunctive syllogism works without contradictory assumptions, but now I'm confused on how this logic can hold true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks badly written. I would have changed it to:

Assume two contradictory premises: A.) 'All ice cream is frozen.'; B.) 'Not all ice cream is frozen.'

[Note: If this is confusing, that's sort of the point. There is nothing wrong with accepting as true a statement and its negation, because you're not aware of the consequences of what you assume in general. The logical consequence of assuming A and B, however, is that you can prove anything as a result, which is seriously wrong. It's not just a bad feeling; it's actual logic.]

Now, just to show that it's possible, say one wants to use those two premises to prove that: C.) 'Words don't exist'.

[That "it" must refer to something in the book before what you quoted. I would guess that "it" is something like "proving anything, under the assumption that you're assuming that two contradictory things are true".]

To do so, construct a disjunction out of A and C: 'All ice cream is frozen or words don't exist.'

[so far, so good. Then I would have continued with:]

Now, "A or C" is true, because we're assuming that A is true, and true "or'ed" with any value is true as well.

[Nothing should have been said about whether C is true or false, because we shouldn't be assuming anything about it at this point. The goal is to show that C MUST be true. Back to the original]

Now use that disjunction for a disjunctive syllogism: 'All ice cream is frozen or words don't exist. Not all ice cream is frozen. Therefore words don't exist.'

[end of rewrite]

Comment: Yes yes! "Nothing should have been said about whether C is true or false, because we shouldn't be assuming anything about it at this point." That nails it

Comment: Carl, this helps, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

We have to remind the definition of *valid* argument :

> An argument from given premisses to a particular conclusion is *valid* if and only if there is no possible situation in which the premisses would be *true* and the conclusion *false*.

If we apply it to your case :

> $$A \lor \lnot C, \lnot A \vdash \lnot C$$

we have that if $A$ is *true*, then $\lnot A$ is *false*; thus, in order to satisfy the second premise : $\lnot A$, we are left with only one possibility : $A$ must be *false*.

If $A$ is *false*, in order to satisfy the first premise : $A \lor \lnot C$ (see truth table for $\lor$) we must have $\lnot C$ *true*.

Thus the conclusion is entailed by the premises and the argument is valid :

> **if** the premises are *true*, **then** the conclusion must be *true* also.

---

When we "apply" the above argument form to a "real life" example, it stay valid, but it licenses us to assert the *truth* of the conclusion only if the premises are both true.

In your case, if we agree that "All ice cream is frozen" ($A$) is *true*, we have that the disjuncttion "All ice cream is frozen or words don't exist" ($A \lor \lnot C$) is also *true*, but the second premise : "Not all ice cream is frozen"  ($\lnot A$) must be *false*, and thus we cannot conclude.

Answer (score 1):

The issue at hand is that the conclusion of a *valid* argument can be *nonsense*.

Quite so.   An argument is sound only if both the form is valid *and* the premises are justified.

Here, you have a valid form, the **disjunctive syllogism**.   However, the premises are quite unjustified.   So it's not sound.